# Multiple belongsTo Associations with Batman.js

Tags: coffeescript, batman.js

I just wanted to check that there was nothing wrong with a model having 2 belongsTo:

```
@belongsTo 'claim'
@belongsTo 'buyer'
```

I ask because I have this and saving does not produce the json it should:

```
create: =>
    alert @claim
    CT.Buyer.find $("#buyer_id").val(), (err, buyer) =>
        @bid.set 'claim', @claim
        @bid.set 'buyer', buyer
        @bid.save()

    return false
```

The `alert @claim` shows me clearly that `@claim` is correct and contains the Claim I expect. But the json sent when `save()` is called looks like:

```
{buyer_id:52c86c74-2425-11e1-8b23-0021cc5da1e1, amount:123}
```

It is not sending `claim_id` for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

It's fine to have multiple belongsTo associations on a model. Are you sure the buyer you are trying to find exists? You should always handle `err` inside `find` callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you `encode`-ing `claim_id` in your model code? Batman.Model won't send back values in it's JSON unless you use [encode](http://batmanjs.org/docs/api/batman.model.html#class_function_encode). For example:

```
class App.Bid extends Batman.Model
  @belongsTo 'claim'
  @belongsTo 'buyer'
  @encode 'claim_id', 'buyer_id'
```

You can also use the `encodeForegnKey` option:

```
class App.Bid extends Batman.Model
  @belongsTo 'claim', encodeForeignKey: true
  @belongsTo 'buyer', encodeForeignKey: true
```